# How to get the div value in the same java tag to proceed further

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to **get the value choosen in select option.** But it was not reflecting in the **java tag**. **I am getting null value** only.I don't **want to use the javascript/jquery.**

Can any one help me to solve this problem.the code i did is:-

```
<div id="nav">
        <select id="certificateGroup"   name="certificateGroup" multiple="multiple" size="25" STYLE="width: 170px" >
        <option value="avaya" selected>Avaya</option>
        <option value="cisco">Cisco</option>
        <option value="dotnet">Dotnet</option>
        <option value="java">Java</option>
        </option>

         </select>

        </div>
        <div id="section">  


        <s:form method="POST" action="skillAssessment.action">
        <input type="button" name="certificateSubmitButton" id="certificateSubmitButton" value="Save" onclick="submitAddOrUpdateCertificateData();">
        </s:form>
           <table id="yourSkillsTable" border="1" style="text-align:left;background:white;width:800px;">
           <thead class="even">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No.</th>
                        <th>Certificate Name</th>
                        <th>Certified or Not</th>
                        <th>Marks</th>
                        <th>Month and year of passing</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >

                <%
                            ValueStack valueStackofCertStack = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
                            List<AssociateCertificateDTO> assoCertificate  = (List<AssociateCertificateDTO>) valueStackofCertStack.findValue("associateCertificate");
                            AssociateCertificateDTO cerdto = null;
                            int sizeofList = (assoCertificate!=null) ? assoCertificate.size() : 0;
                            String  certified="certified";
                            int a=0;
                            for (a=0;a<sizeofList; a++) {
                                cerdto = assoCertificate.get(a);
                                if(cerdto.getCertificateGroupName().equals("Avaya")){

                        %>
```

**How can i get the option selected in the "select id=certificateGroup" ?**

Comment: Where you try to take this select value??

Comment: i want to replace "Avaya" in if condition by the selected option....Can this is possible?